# Using forall() predicate in minizinc as assignment statement without 'constraint'

Tags: optimization, scheduler, mathematical-optimization, minizinc

I have a Minizinc program for generating the optimal charge/discharge schedule for a grid-connected battery, given a set of prices by time-interval.

My program works (sort of; subject to some caveats), but my question is about  two 'constraint' statements which are really just assignment statements:

```
constraint forall(t in 2..T)(MW_SETPOINT[t-1] - SALE[t] = MW_SETPOINT[t]);
constraint forall(t in 1..T)(PROFIT[t] = SALE[t] * PRICE[t]);
```

These just mean Energy `SALES` is the delta in `MW_SETPOINT` from `t-1` to `1`, and `PROFIT` is `SALE` * `PRICE` for each interval. So it seems counterintuitive to me to declare them as 'constraints'. But I've been unable to formulate them as assignment statements without throwing syntax errors.

Question:

- Is there a more idiomatic way to declare such assignment statements for an array which is a function of other params/variables? Or is making assignments for arrays in `constraint`s the recommended/idiomatic way to do it in Minizinc?

Full program for context:

```
% PARAMS
int: MW_CAPACITY = 10;
array[int] of float: PRICE; 

% DERIVED PARAMS
int: STARTING_MW = MW_CAPACITY div 2;  % integer division
int: T = length(PRICE);

% DECISION VARIABLE - MW SETPOINT EACH INTERVAL
array[1..T] of var 0..MW_CAPACITY: MW_SETPOINT;

% DERIVED/INTERMEDIATE VARIABLES
array[1..T] of var -1*MW_CAPACITY..MW_CAPACITY: SALE;  
array[1..T] of var float: PROFIT;
var float: NET_PROFIT = sum(PROFIT);

% CONSTRAINTS
%% If start at 5MW, and sell 5 first interval, setpoint for first interval is 0 
constraint MW_SETPOINT[1] = STARTING_MW - SALE[1];  

%% End where you started; opt schedule from arbitrage means no net MW over time
constraint MW_SETPOINT[T] = STARTING_MW;            

%% these are really justassignment statements for SALE & PROFIT
constraint forall(t in 2..T)(MW_SETPOINT[t-1] - SALE[t] = MW_SETPOINT[t]);
constraint forall(t in 1..T)(PROFIT[t] = SALE[t] * PRICE[t]);

% OBJECTIVE: MAXIMIZE REVENUE
solve maximize NET_PROFIT;

output["DAILY_PROFIT: " ++ show(NET_PROFIT) ++ 
      "\nMW SETPOINTS: " ++ show(MW_SETPOINT) ++ 
      "\nMW SALES: " ++ show(SALE) ++
      "\n$/MW PRICES: " ++ show(PRICE)++
      "\nPROFITS: " ++ show(PROFIT)
      ];
```

It can be run with

````
minizinc opt_sched_hindsight.mzn --solver org.minizinc.mip.coin-bc -D "PRICE = [29.835, 29.310470000000002, 28.575059999999997, 28.02416, 28.800690000000003, 32.41052, 34.38542, 29.512390000000003, 25.66587, 25.0499, 26.555529999999997, 28.149440000000002, 30.216509999999996, 32.32415, 31.406609999999997, 36.77642, 41.94735, 51.235209999999995, 50.68137, 64.54481, 48.235170000000004, 40.27663, 34.93675, 31.10404];"```
````

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can play with [**Array Comprehensions**](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.4.2/en/spec.html#array-comprehensions): *(quote from the docs)*

> Array comprehensions have this syntax:
>
> ```
> <array-comp> ::= "[" <expr> "|" <comp-tail> "]"
> ```
>
> For example (with the literal equivalents on the right):
>
> ```
> [2*i | i in 1..5]       % [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
> ```
>
> Array comprehensions have more flexible type and inst requirements than set comprehensions (see [Set Comprehensions](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.4.2/en/spec.html#spec-set-comprehensions)).
>
> Array comprehensions are allowed over a variable set with finite type,
>   the result is an array of optional type, with length equal to the
>   cardinality of the upper bound of the variable set. For example:
>
> ```
> var set of 1..5: x;
> array[int] of var opt int: y = [ i * i | i in x ];
> ```
>
> The length of array will be 5.
>
> Array comprehensions are allowed where the where-expression
>   is a `var bool`. Again the resulting array is of optional
>   type, and of length equal to that given by the generator expressions. For example:
>
> ```
> var int x;
> array[int] of var opt int: y = [ i | i in 1..10 where i != x ];
> ```
>
> The length of the array will be 10.
>
> The indices of an evaluated simple array comprehension are
>   implicitly `1..n`, where `n` is the length of the evaluated
>   comprehension.

**Example:**

```js
int: MW_CAPACITY = 10;
int: STARTING_MW = MW_CAPACITY div 2;

array [int] of float: PRICE = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0];
int: T = length(PRICE);

array [1..T] of var -1*MW_CAPACITY..MW_CAPACITY: SALE;

array [1..T] of var 0..MW_CAPACITY: MW_SETPOINT = let {
        int: min_i = min(index_set(PRICE));
    } in  
        [STARTING_MW - sum([SALE[j] | j in min_i..i])
         | i in index_set(PRICE)];

array [1..T] of var float: PROFIT =
        [SALE[i] * PRICE[i]
         | i in index_set(PRICE)];

solve satisfy;
```

Output:

```sh
~$ minizinc test.mzn 
SALE = array1d(1..4, [-10, -5, 0, 0]);
----------
```

Notice that `index_set(PRICE)` is nothing else but `1..T` and that `min(index_set(PRICE))` is nothing else but `1`, so one could write the above **array comprehensions** also as

```js
array [1..T] of var 0..MW_CAPACITY: MW_SETPOINT =
        [STARTING_MW - sum([SALE[j] | j in 1..i])
         | i in 1..T];

array [1..T] of var float: PROFIT =
        [SALE[i] * PRICE[i]
         | i in 1..T];
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks, array comprehensions are exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @MaxPower they can also be used also for higher-order arrays by casting the 1.D array to the required N-D dimension. Both `if ... then ... else ... endif` and `let {} in ...` can be used inside the expression when dealing with complex array generators.